# What is the difference between PDO fetchAll() and fetch_all()?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm trying to fetch the data from database using prepared statement. I'm new in PDO so I searched about it. Below are the two different pattern giving me same result.

### Pattern 1

```
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=dummy_db;host=localhost","root","");
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$statement->execute();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($results);
```

### Pattern 2

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from mytable");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
```

Above both pattern giving me almost same result, so I wanted to know which one is good for fetching the data and what are the difference between them. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is interesting question.

Although you are probably unaware of the fact that the second code snippet has nothing to do with PDO and belongs to mysqli, still the question makes some sense.

Because PDO's `fetchAll()` is WAY more useful than simple `fetch_all()` from mysqli, thanks to `PDO::FETCH` constants, letting you fetch the data in [dozens different formats](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall).

This is one of the reasons why PDO is recommended over mysqli.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge, the link (you mentioned in the answer) is very good and has a lot of best and short patterns for fetching the data.